# Automatically Import Image into Posts from URLs on the Web?

Tags: plugins, images

Is there a way for me to add an `<img>` tag in a Post, but then have a plugin download that image, and put it on the server for me instead of me needing to manually download the file from online to my computer and then upload it to the server?

Thanks

Comment: You can also run it afterwards instead of on-demand: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3442/retrieving-and-storing-images-linked-from-other-domains-on-local-server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure. You could hook the [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) action, use `WP_Http` class to download it and then insert it as an attachment using [`wp_insert_attachment`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) and [`wp_update_attachment_metadata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_attachment_metadata).

It's not trivial but shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: I've built similar systems before ... you can go further and make the plug-in automatically re-size the image for your purposes, too.  There's no reason to store a 1024x600 image on the server if you're only displaying it as 256x150.

Comment: Yeah, I wish I (or someone else) had time to code up a plugin for this. Maybe after I get some client work done... :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called "[Add Linked Images To Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-linked-images-to-gallery-v01/)" - when you insert an image to your post from an external website, this plugin automatically save a local copy and replace the link to the external site with the local address. 
hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a newer plugin in the Wordpress repository which works. Add Linked images to Gallery does not work anymore. [Import External Images](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/import-external-images/)