# How to retrieve image from URL and set as featured image/post thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails

Given a Vimeo ID, I can retrieve a thumbnail from the video via Vimeo Simple API. Rather than call the API every time my page loads I want to set the image as the post thumbnail using the `save_post` hook (similar to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/784/automatically-import-image-into-posts-from-urls-on-the-web)).

My problem is that I am not familiar with URL calls in php. I would like to know:

1. the benefits/drawbacks of using a method like curl compared to `WP_Http`. Is one "better" than the other?
2. the order in which I should call functions to successfully set the post thumbnail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Has anyone figured this out? I'm trying to do this as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My favorite way of handling this problem has been to use a little documented function I discovered on another stack post: [`media_sideload_image`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19637/media-sideload-image-generates-blank)

It works by fetching an image url to the WordPress upload dir and then associating  the image to a post's attachments.

You can try it like so:

```
// required libraries for media_sideload_image
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

// $post_id == the post you want the image to be attached to
// $video_thumb_url == the vimeo video's thumb url
// $description == optional description

// load the image
$result = media_sideload_image($video_thumb_url, $post_id, $description);

// then find the last image added to the post attachments
$attachments = get_posts(array('numberposts' => '1', 'post_parent' => $post_id, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC'));


if(sizeof($attachments) > 0){
    // set image as the post thumbnail
    set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attachments[0]->ID);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Hi **@David John Smith**:

1.) If you are in WordPress, (almost) always use `WP_Http`; it's one of the many things I love about working with WordPress. Why call it and not CURL?  Well, because it has a nicer syntax and it calls CURL if CURL is available. If not, it chooses from one of 3 other options. So it really is a brilliant piece of kit.

2.) To answer the 2nd question I'll need to know how you want to name the files you are downloading?

Comment: Thanks Mike. As for the post thumbnails, I don't really care how they're named, I would just like to be able to access them as related to a post, either by `post_thumbnail()` or `get_post_meta()`. I guess it would make sense to name it with the post ID.

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: @NetConstructor - It's really hard to keep track of questions that are in a "pending" state, so no.  I just created a "pending" folder on my bookmarks bar, I'll see if I can't be more consistent with that. But, I don't have time right now for this one so will have to come back to it.

Comment: @Mike -- thanks Mike, just thought you might have had a solution here cause among other things you seem to be the master of this stuff :-)

Comment: @NetConstructor.com - LOL! Thanks, I'm just master of the debugger, that is all. :)

Comment: I just discovered `media_sideload_image()`, which seems to make the whole process very simple. Huzzah for functions.php!