# How to access featured image?

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails, attachments

I saw [this code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3029/how-to-retrieve-image-from-url-and-set-as-featured-image-post-thumbnail?rq=1) as how to set a featured image for a post:

```
// required libraries for media_sideload_image
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

// $post_id == the post you want the image to be attached to
// $video_thumb_url == the vimeo video's thumb url
// $description == optional description

// load the image
$result = media_sideload_image($video_thumb_url, $description);

// then find the last image added to the post attachments
$attachments = get_posts(array('numberposts' => '1', 'post_parent' => $post_id, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC'));


if(sizeof($attachments) > 0){
    // set image as the post thumbnail
    set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attachments[0]->ID);
}
```

But how do I get that information when I retrieve a post? Is there a property or method that I use?

Comment: Do you wanted get post featured image url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`get_the_post_thumbnail ( $post/$post_id, $sizes, $attr )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/)  will give you the featured image as html to output.
- [`get_post_thumbnail_id ( get_the_ID ( ) )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_thumbnail_id/) will give you the ID of the featured image so you can use it to get more information. Getting the thumbnail ID is essentially accessing the the post's meta data:

  `$image_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_thumbnail_id', true )`

---

- [`wp_get_attachment_metadata ( $attachment_id, $unfiltered )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata) will give you all the meta data associated with the image.
- [`wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size, $icon )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) will give you an array of information for a particular size.

---

```
 [0] => url
 [1] => width
 [2] => height
 [3] => boolean: true if $url is a resized image, false if it is the original or if no image is available.
```

---

In the above example you can get the src and id using:

```
$image_src  = media_sideload_image($video_thumb_url, $description, 'src');
$image_id   = attachment_url_to_postid($image_src); 
set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $image_id );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()));
```

above code get current featured image url. I hope it work for you.